# Is it worth reconsidering the question "Why solve a problem with a class and not a function?"

Tags: discussion

[Why solve a problem with a class and not a function?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347640/why-classes-and-objects-c)

I've heavily edited this question to make it's meaning clear.  I did this at -5 votes while it had 3 close votes.  Am I wasting our time or is this now a reasonable question?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is currently not worth it, since it still is not really clear what the OP meant (therefore I voted to close as "unclear"). Moreover, for any of the interpretations I can think of there also some older questions which are probably duplicates.